# Ink template issues on ios browser

Tags: html, ios, email, templates, zurb-ink

I'm building html email templates with Ink foundation and facing the following issue.

In ios Safari browser I've tested on gmail, yahoo and yandex emails and the templates are shown minified,with smaller fonts. And when I'm checking not in the browser but for example on ios yahoo email app or icloud email, the email templates look right and fonts are displayed correctly.

I've tested the Ink foundation basic template 
http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/basic.html 
and realized that it also has the same font minifying issue. I'm attaching the screenshots of minified look (left image) and correct view from email apps (middle image).

In Gmail it brings also the following warning message: "This message has been modified to fit your screen. Tap here to show original." and it is showing a bad modified variant (right image). And when you click to show the original, it shows the variant with minified fonts.

Here's a link to images http://kadmos.li/web/email-screens.png

I've tested the emails with Putsmail test service.

May anyone help me to understand what causes to have such issues on a well-tested email framework?

Regards, Lilit

Answer (score 0):

Try quick fix for gmail:
Add to last child of your table

```
<table><tr> YOUR HTML </tr><tr> <!--start fix display gmail--><div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div><!--end fix display gmail--></tr></table>
```